# Is it good or bad to get a puppy from a mother who has had her first litter?

Tags: dogs, breeding

I am looking to get a Rhodesian Ridgeback puppy. However the breeder that is expecting to sell soon said that the puppies will be from a mother who will have her very first litter.

I just would like everyone's thought on this. Is it OK in terms of risk to puppy health etc? Is it better to get a puppy from an experienced bitch?

Please assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it better the be the first child, the second or the third?

While it might matter, other things are way more important: a safe and clean home to grow up in with loving parents.

For puppies these things are more important:

1. healthy parents with no behaviour problems.
2. No known health and genetic defects.
3. A clean and safe home to grow up in.
4. And then some proper socializing and training.
5. Then, and maybe then, a first time mother maybe matters. (it probably will not)